# How to open and select a subset of images from .rec file in python?

Tags: python, mxnet

I have a folder containing the following files: train.idx, train.rec, property, lfw.bin, cfp_fp.bin, agedb_30.bin

This folder contains face images.

I have already used ImageRecordIter in the following code.

However everytime that I print the first element of train_data I get a different image.

```
train_data = ImageRecordIter(
    path_imgrec = os.path.join(rec_path,'train.rec'),
    path_imgidx = os.path.join(rec_path, 'train.idx'),
    label_width = 2,

    data_shape  = (3,112,112 ),
    batch_size  = 10,
    shuffle     = False)
```

My questions are:

1) I do not know how data is usually stored in these types of files, e.g. which one contains labels. Any idea about these types of files?

2) How can I extract a subset of data to make a sample file? Also, what would be the file format (e.g. pickle file, txt file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only using the `train.rec` and `train.idx` in the `ImageRecordIter` so they are the only files being used. Your labels will be stored (alongside the data) in the `train.rec` file. You could use [`MXIndexedRecordIO`](https://mxnet.apache.org/api/python/docs/api/mxnet/recordio/index.html#mxnet.recordio.MXIndexedRecordIO) to extract random samples from these files. Something like:

```
samples = []
record = mx.recordio.MXIndexedRecordIO('tmp.idx', 'tmp.rec', 'r')
for i in range(5):
    samples.append(record.read_idx(i))

record = mx.recordio.MXIndexedRecordIO('tmp.idx', 'tmp.rec', 'w')
for i, sample in enumerate(samples):
    record.write_idx(i, sample)
record.close()
```